# How can I add a line break between my inline-block javascript divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to display tiles in one large variable grid using html/javascript. I've managed to display divs with the inline-block with my code below, but I can't seem to get a line break. For example, after each 10 tiles, I would like a new line to start. This would create a 10 by 10 grid.

```
function cdiv() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.width = "100px";
  div.style.height = "100px";
  div.style.background = "red";
  div.style.color = "white";
  div.style.display = "inline-block"
  div.innerHTML = 'hello';

  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  for (b = 0; b < 10; b++) { 
    cdiv();
  }
}
```

I would appreciate a bonus tip in how to give each of these divs a unique ID for further tinkering.

Comment: `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"))`? https://jsfiddle.net/45381qx9/

Comment: I have the exact same code as yours now but it won't work for me. Yours is perfect though. https://jsfiddle.net/45381qx9/

Comment: This can be done with css alone

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/using-the-div-tag-to-create-tables.html

Comment: Further to charlieftl's comment, to show *one* CSS approach: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6rrv3x37/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inner loop , append a break line "br"

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (b = 0; b < 10; b++) { 
    cdiv();
  }
  //Append line break here...      
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br")); //Thanks Squint hint as well
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to wrap all div in a container which has width 10 times of each div. Please refer to code below and this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/5uc2nc3p/2/

```
function cdiv(ele) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.width = "100px";
  div.style.height = "100px";
  div.style.background = "red";
  div.style.color = "white";
  div.style.display = "inline-block"
  div.innerHTML = 'hello';

 ele.appendChild(div);
}

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "1000px"; ///10 times of inner divs
div.style["overflow-y"]= "visible"; // to show overflow
document.body.appendChild(div);
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (b = 0; b < 10; b++) { 
    cdiv(div);
  }
}
```

Comment: On your jfiddle I see that the tiles extend past the page view horizontally, which is what I want. However, when I try a large number of tiles in my index file and open it in chrome, I don't get the scroll occurring. Instead I see lines of tiles that fit my page horizontally and don't go past it. I was hoping for a perfectly square grid.

Comment: have you tried setting overflow to visible for container of div or body ?

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to do that, but searching up now. If you have a good link to for how that's done I'd appreciate it

Comment: I have updated my answer to include it. You can do div.style["overflow-y"]= "visible";

Comment: Best would be to set overflow of body if above thing does't work. Add this to your css   body{  overflow:visible;}

Comment: that works on jfiddle. I'm actually also trying it in a notepad and opening in chrome as an html file, which doesn't allow horrizontal scroll. But yes, I like the css body overflow idea. That was great

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script>
function cdiv() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.width = "100px";
  div.style.height = "100px";
  div.style.background = "red";
  div.style.color = "white";
  div.style.display = "inline-block"
  div.innerHTML = 'hello';

  document.body.appendChild(div);
  
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  for (b = 0; b < 10; b++) { 
cdiv();
 }
}
</script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

`document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));` use this line to add break in your first loop.

Comment: I tried that as @squint had suggested above, but it didn't work. His method works where he added the break line after the inner loop completes